# Issues when attempting to modify an emoji sequence

Tags: swift, emoji

I have the following function that takes a string with emojis, if its a sequence emoji a+b it will leave a as is and it will change b to a different emoji

```
func changeEmoji(givenString:String)->(String){

 let emojiDictionary :[String:String] = [
"⛹" : "⛹",
"♀️" : "",
"" : "",
"♂️" :"",
]

let stringCharacters=Array(givenString.characters)
var returnedString=String()

for character in stringCharacters{

if emojiDictionary[String(character)] == nil {
    return "error"
}
else {
     returnedString=returnedString+emojiDictionary[String(character)]!
}
}
return  returnedString
}
```

i have no problem with

```
  changeEmoji(givenString: "⛹⛹")
```

it outputs:   "⛹⛹"

but:

```
 changeEmoji(givenString: "⛹⛹⛹‍♀️")
```

outputs "error" while it shouldn't as  ♀ Female Sign and Variation Selector-16 is the second key in my emojiDictionary.. 
Similar issue appears with male sign and variation selector.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Sorry i dont get you. Firstly, the second string is different to the one you have written, secondly as per http://emojipedia.org/woman-with-ball-type-1-2/ the character in question is supposed to have a zero width joiner.

Comment: ah sorry, my bad. I was not aware of that sequence

Comment: Could you try and copy paste my code to your Xcode playground and tell me if you have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I get the same result. The problem is that "⛹‍♀️" is made up of 3 Swift Characters (⛹‍, ‍, ♀️) – where the Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick Type-1-2 "‍" is suffixed by a zero width joiner. Therefore it doesn't match the "" character in your dictionary, that doesn't include a zero width joiner. What's your expected output for "⛹‍♀️"? The simplest solution may be to just add the "‍" (modifier with zero width joiner) character as another key to your dictionary.

Comment: I dont think the issue is due to what you are describing, considering that ⛹ is type 1-2 and it also has a zero width joiner but if you enter it in the function it does not show error.. Regardless, i did try entering ‍ + zero width joiner as key, i also tried entering just the width joiner as key, nothing! Baffling huh?! I ve been kicking myself for the past week! The desired output for the ⛹‍♀️ would have been ⛹

Comment: "⛹" only has two code points, U+26F9 (Person with ball) and U+1F3FB (Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick Type-1-2), with no zero width joiners – which is why it works in the function :) Am I to take it that adding ‍ + zero width joiner as a key to your dictionary worked? Adding only a zero width joiner as a key shouldn't work, as the "‍" (modifier + zwj) is a single character (aka extended grapheme cluster), so will compare false against just a zwj.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123645/discussion-between-do2-and-hamish).

Comment: I have one more question about this..:) please see chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "⛹‍♀️" is made up of 3 Swift `Character`s (aka extended grapheme clusters):

- "⛹‍" (U+26F9 PERSON WITH BALL)
- "‍" (U+1F3FB Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick Type-1-2, U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER)
- "♀️" (U+2640  FEMALE SIGN, U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16)

However, your `emojiDictionary` only contains a "" (U+1F3FB Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick Type-1-2), which doesn't match the second `Character` of "⛹‍♀️" as it's missing the zero width joiner.

The simplest solution therefore is to just add another key to your dictionary to include the Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick Type-1-2 character, with a zero width joiner suffix. The clearest way of doing this would be to just suffix it with the unicode escape sequence `\u{200D}`.

For example:

```
func changeEmoji(givenString: String) -> String? {

    // I have included the unicode point breakdowns for clarity
    let emojiDictionary : [String : String] = [
        "⛹" : "⛹", // 26F9 : 26F9
        "♀️" : "", // 2640, fe0f : 1f469
        "" : "", // 1f3fb : 1f4a4
        "\u{200D}" : "", // 1f3fb, 200d : 1f4a4
        "♂️" :"" // 2642, fe0f : 1f468
        ]

    // Convert characters of string to an array of string characters,
    // given that you're just going to use the String(_:) initialiser later.
    let stringCharacters = givenString.characters.map(String.init(_:))
    var returnedString = ""

    for character in stringCharacters {
        guard let replacementCharacter = emojiDictionary[character] else {
            // I would advise making your method return an optional
            // in cases where the string can't be converted.
            // Failure is shown by the return of nil, rather than some
            // string sentinel.
            return nil
        }
        returnedString += replacementCharacter
    }
    return returnedString
}

print(changeEmoji(givenString: "⛹⛹⛹‍♀️")) // Optional("⛹⛹⛹")
```